# Using Html.BeginForm inside section razor layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a _Layout page with two sections: **@RenderSection("LeftContent", False)** and **@RenderSection("MainContent", False)**

All works perfectlly with another page that uses this Layout, except submit don do anything, I mean submit do not call HttpPost:

```
@ModelType iSAM.PROVINCIA

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Create"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

@section LeftContent
    Add navigation menu
End Section

@section MainContent
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @Using Html.BeginForm()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "Error al crear el registro. Revise los errores e intente nuevamente.")

    @<fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.DESC_PROVINCIA, "Name:")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.DESC_PROVINCIA, New With {.style = "text-transform:uppercase"})
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    @<div>
            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "ListProvincias", "_Layout", New With {.area = ""}, New With {.class = "imgBack", .title = "Back"})
    </div>

    End Using
End Section
```

If I left the code outside **MainContent section** it works. There's a way to make it work inside this section?
Regards.

Comment: Why do you have `@<fieldset>` and `@<div>`?

Comment: otherwise I get error: __Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" runat="server" />
```

Remove the runat="server" and it should work fine. Old web-form habits die hard = )

**Edit:**

While the above is an issue, it wasn't the root of the problem. The issue here was there was a `@Html.BeginForm` in BOTH the MasterPage and inside the content section, meaning two forms were defined and thus caused the one defined in the content section to not function.

Comment: That usually is always the issue. Is there a javascript error being thrown? Is it possible the validation is failing and not displaying a message?

Comment: Everything it's ok, as I said if I put ouside **section** the HttpPost is called

Comment: Well if the `MainContent` portion of the MasterFile already has a form defined, then you're defining the form twice: once in the layout and then once inside of the section definition.

Comment: Having a form within a form is always going to mess something up. Can you remove the first instance of the `@Html.BeginForm()` in your master page?

Comment: Ok. I remove the form from Layout and it works. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Great! No problem = ) I'm going to edit my original answer to include the correct solution.